# Thor - command line option not recognized in method

Tags: ruby, thor

I have to use this command to run my `ruby` program:

```
$ruby filename.rb NAME --from="People" --yell
```

And I have the script like this:

```
require 'thor'

class CLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"

  method_option :from, :required => true
  method_option :yell, :type => :boolean
  def self.hello(name)
    output = []
    output << "from: #{options[:from]}" if options[:from]
    output << "Hello #{name}"
    output = output.join("\n")
    puts options[:yell] ? output.upcase : output
  end
end

CLI.hello(ARGV)
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
c:\RubyWorkplace\Assignment1>ruby testing.rb Jay --from="Ray"
FROM: #<THOR::OPTION:0X000000031D7998>
HELLO ["JAY", "--FROM=RAY"]

c:\RubyWorkplace\Assignment1>ruby testing.rb Jay --from="Ray" --yell
FROM: #<THOR::OPTION:0X0000000321E528>
HELLO ["JAY", "--FROM=RAY", "--YELL"]
```

It looks like `:yell` always works no matter I specify it or not, and `options` are all read as `name` input in the `hello` method.

I found and tried many ways from online tutorials but the problem wasn't solved. Please tell me what has been gone wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by I am calling `CLI.hello ARGV` in the script. when the program runs, it will call `hello` method and recognize all command line inputs as `hello`'s parameter, which is an array.

One of the ways to fix this problem is making `hello` public by removing `self`, the call the script by `start` method.

```
require 'thor'

class CLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"

  method_option :from, :required => true
  method_option :yell, :type => :boolean
  def hello(name)
    #do something
  end
end

CLI.start ARGV
```